# How to compare values in jsp using JSP Expression Language (EL)

Tags: jsp, el, equals, andromda

I have this check in my jsp:

```
<logic:equal name="${product.status}" value="${ProductStatuses.SOLD}"> 
   // do something
</logic:equal>

<logic:equal name="${product.status}" value="${ProductStatuses.IN_STOCK}"> 
   // do something else
</logic:equal>
```

Both checks return true, so obviously something is not OK.
The product's `status` is of type `int` and here is my ProductStatuses class which is automatically generated by AndroMDA and hence is in a .jar:

```
public interface ProductStatuses {
    /**
     * @author andromda
     */
    int SOLD = 1;

    /**
     * @author andromda
     */
    int IN_STOCK = 2;

    /**
     * @author andromda
     */
    int N_A = 0;
}
```

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have a solution. The comparaison in the jsp wasn't good. Here is how it works:

```
<logic:equal name="product" property="status" value="<%=String.valueOf(ProductStatuses.SOLD)%>">   
    // do something
</logic:equal>

<logic:equal name="product" property="status" value="<%=String.valueOf(ProductStatuses.IN_STOCK)%>">   
    // do something else
</logic:equal>
```